# Alternative to slow grep

Tags: unix, command-line, grep

Currently I have a system log (Growl.app in this case) that I'd like to see from time to time.
I use grep to filter out the lines I do not wish to see.

```
cat /Users/Daniel/Library/Logs/Growl.log | grep -vE 'registered|Display frame|Reserving|Used rects|Beginning a pass|Successfully reserved|Adjusted display frame|---|User went idle|User returned|positionDisplay|primaryDirection|Bowtie:|secondaryDirection' | tail -20 > /Users/Daniel/Library/Logs/Growl-log.txt
sleep 2
qlmanage -p /Users/Daniel/Library/Logs/Growl-log.txt
```

I'm not sure if there's a better way to filter out the information but as it is my script takes quite a bit of time to process that command. I may as well add the my hardware is definitely not holding it back. Another thing to note is the 'qlmanage' part is an OS X specific command that displays the text file's contents in a 'quick look' window. It is instantaneous when displaying requests.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not helping that you're doing `cat filename | grep 'patterns'`.  Give grep the filename directly: `grep 'patterns' filename`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking the system to read a really big, probably continuously growing file, remove a bunch of records based on a large number of searches( each alternation : |z|c|V ..etc).  And every time you ask it to run it has to plow through ever more records.

Does the log have a timestamp?  In conjunction with a timestamp (or even better,tail) , grep, and  you can have a job run for you every day or every hour that has what you want right there in a far smaller file.

Basically you cannot read 100's of MB doing all that you ask in a few seconds.  Let's start with tail, which works by positioning a file pointer instead of reading the whole file.  Faster.

```
tail -20000 /Users/Daniel/Library/Logs/Growl.log | 
grep -vE 'registered|Display frame|Reserving|Used rects|Beginning a pass|Successfully reserved|Adjusted display frame|---|User went idle|User returned|positionDisplay|primaryDirection|Bowtie:|secondaryDirection' |
> /Users/Daniel/Library/Logs/Growl-log.txt
qlmanage -p /Users/Daniel/Library/Logs/Growl-log.txt
```

Adjust the 20000  to get a reasonable nunber of samples  that pass your filter.  In other words `prefilter` the file by removing early records which you will pitch anyway.

Another speed up is to do a positive search - grep for what you want, rather than what you do not want.

Congratulations.You also won the UUOC award.  Try Mr google for the the term `UUOC` (has to do with cat).  Everyone has won the award before they learned about it

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I really was not aware of how big the original log file had grown (I really should have investigated it before making this question thread).
Now I just need to truncate the log to something a tad more recent. A task that should be fairly easy to automate.